# Excel setting different fill color for value VBA

Tags: excel, formatting, excel-2010, vba

Looking for a solution to assign fill colors to a cell containing different names if they are appear with multiple values in another column. I am using a Countif formula to identify them, which works well. Currently I have a conditional formatting assigning a fill color for all that are above the 0 in formula to fill color, but I want each different value to be a different color. On any given file there could be 1 to 10 different names, and they can be different names all the time. Help much appreciated.

Formula for reference cell RC23

```
=COUNTIFS(C[-1],RC[-1],C[-20],""<>""&RC[-20])
```

Conditional formatting (Range may seem long and awkward but needed as I use two other conditionals that each effect different cells and when I leave off Range( _ they stop working correctly.)

```
Range( _
    "A178:T178,A164:T175,A160,D160:K160,M160:R160,T160,A156:T158,A146:T151,A119:T125,A115:T116,A110:T113,A106:T108,A85:T104,A75:T83,A73:T73,A64:T71,A62:T62,A60:T60,A180:T1048576,A127:T144" _
    ).Select
Range("L:L").Activate
Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=(RC23>0)"
Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
    .Pattern = xlLightUp
    .PatternThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent3
    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent1
    .TintAndShade = 0.599963377788629
    .PatternTintAndShade = 0.599963377788629
```

Comment: You select a large non-contiguous range of cells then immediately discard it for L:L. Where are you trying to put the conditional formatting? (i.e. what is the intended `Applies to:` ?)

Comment: I am applying this particular format to the L column cells. I am parsing together both macros I have written in excel as well as the great advice I have gotten on here. I do know it is terrible coding but it does work, and when I monkey with that Range.Select other Format Conditions stop working correctly. So I am working toward getting my needs working then I will seek to clean up the code. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best Solution I could devise was to create a column auto assigning at number based for each duplicate value. Then apply conditional formatting for each number. I programmed for up to ten duplications in VBA if the column returns 1-10 with the various colors.
This was made possible with some [formula help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31587573/5098919)

Open to other suggestions.